# What does 'of' mean in "It's this friend of mine"?

Tags: prepositions, vocabulary

> As such, any uncle **of hers** would be minor royalty, even if illegitimate. ([daum.net](http://dic.daum.net/search.do?q=any%20*%20of%20hers&dic=eng))

When I saw this structure, I would thought that the preposition ‘*of*’ presents **a set** (=*a set of her uncles*) and ‘*any uncle*’ is part of the set. But reading this sentence - “*Not me, exactly, no. It’s this friend **of mine** who has a matter to talk over with her*” - from a novel, *Dona Flor and Her Two Husbands*, I would think ‘*of*’ means ‘***that belongs to***; **that has the property of**’. I’m afraid some would say it’s not a big deal. But isn’t it worth to think of, or to be told about from sincere natives?

Comment: See CGEL pages 468-9.

Comment: @snailplane, Thank you so much. In fact, I've tried yet stopped before finding the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preposition *of* is used to express the [possession](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/of), definition #9 a.

[Usage note](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/of): Grammarians have sometimes objected to the so called double genitive construction, as in a friend of my father’s; a book of mine. But the construction has been used in English since the 14th century and serves a useful purpose: it can help sort out ambiguous phrase.

Comment: #8 would be better connected with the OP

Comment: Right, but #9 uses the word *possession*.